# How can I check the ruby format for a bunch of files and/or a single file?

Tags: files, ruby

Most of them have a common pattern that is a filename of ..._rspec.rb

One of them is a filename without that ending (but does end in .rb).

How can I run `ruby -wc` (or in fact any operations such as `cat ls`, etc.) on these files as well as on a single file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following program will do that

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/target
# First the tests:
for program in `ls ~/target/*_rspec.rb`
do
  file=`echo $program | sed "s|$PWD/||"`
  echo "Testing ruby format for $file" - `ruby -wc $program`
done
# and then the page objects file:
echo "Testing ruby format for page_object_methods.rb" - `ruby -wc $PWD/page_object_methods.rb`
```